# How to say "Thank you for your time yesterday..." in correct spanish?

Tags: traducción

How to properly say:

> Thank you for your time yesterday, we were very happy to meet you.

I've seen various ways but don't know what is the right translation...

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! Could you please share with us those possible translations you have already seen or tried?

Comment: Well one of them is;  Gracias por tu tiempo ayer.
Nos alegramos de verte/ Nos alegramos mucho de conocerte.                                                                                      What would be the right translation?

Comment: @Jonasmarc please [edit] your question with such useful information. It may also be good to you to give a look to [ask]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spanish (at least in Spain) the expression "gracias por tu tiempo" is used in the context of business (where the very busy people are), and does not sound strange. You can even find ocurrences of that expression in the Spanish corpus since 2002. So the first part of your choice is correct: "Gracias por tu tiempo ayer". Other options:

- Gracias por dedicarnos tiempo ayer.
- Gracias por encontrar tiempo para nosotros ayer.

As for the second part, the verb "meet" can be tricky because in Spanish it can be both "quedar [con alguien]", "ver [a alguien]" or even "conocer [a alguien por primera vez]". So the translation in this case depends heavily on the context, and that's why we always ask for a context and some previous effort when asking questions.

Assuming that the context places the speaker in the first meeting of several people, my choices would be:

- Estuvimos encantados de conocerle/te.
- Nos alegró mucho conocerle/te.

The context will also determine if you must use "conocerle" or "conocerte". And what's more, these sentences are valid in the Spanish from Spain. If you need translation to other variant of Spanish, you should indicate it in the tags (that's what tags are for), tagging the question with [españa](/questions/tagged/espa%c3%b1a), [méxico](/questions/tagged/m%c3%a9xico) or [español-neutral](/questions/tagged/espa%c3%b1ol-neutral) if you don't have location restrictions.

Comment: Concerte would not be very appropiate here. Because even though we've never met the person personally (it was the first time), we've known him a long time and speak regularly (phone). What can I use instead?

Comment: @Jonasmarc you can use the same verb, adding *[en persona](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SjUIL8Z#57j1eEq)*. So the sentence would be *nos alegró mucho conocerle en persona*. All this information is useful for us to help you get a better answer, so make sure to add as many details as you can the next time. :-)